# php fopen with ssh2.sftp is failing with special characters

Tags: special-characters, fopen

The below is working just fine

```
$stream = fopen($connection_string . "/var/tmp/test.test", 'r');
```

But

```
$stream = fopen($connection_string . "/var/tmp/test.#test", 'r');
```

Fails with an error message:
Warning: fopen(): Unable to open ssh2.sftp://Resource id #108/var/tmp/test.#test on remote host in...

test.test and test#test are working fine, only the combination of test.#test is failing.

ssh2_scp_recv() handles test.#test just fine.

CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
PHP 5.2.17

Is this a php bug? Or some special character escaping is required?

Answer (score 2):

it would be interesting to know how well it works with phpseclib. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

// outputs the contents of filename.remote to the screen
echo $sftp->get('filename.remote');
// copies filename.remote to filename.local from the SFTP server
$sftp->get('filename.remote', 'filename.local');
?>
```

src: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#get

if phpseclib didn't work you could enable logging, with phpseclib, and see what the phpseclib logs say. eg. do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);` after you include `Net/SFTP.php` and then do `$sftp->getLog()` after you try to download the file.